# Having difficulties displaying my model in my view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to MVC5 and I am building a simple application that can add two numbers.
**Model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Test.Models
{
    public class Solve
    {
        public  decimal a { get; set; }
        public  decimal b { get; set; }
        public decimal Result { get; set; }
    }
 }
```

This is my controller
 **Controller**

```
namespace Test.Controllers
{
    public class SolveController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Solve
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
          return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Solve equation)
        {

            equation.Result = equation.a + equation.b;
            ViewBag.Message = equation;
            return View();
        }
```

**View**

```
@model Test.Models.Solve

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>


<form method="post">
  First Value: <input type="number" name="a"/><br /><br />
  Second Value: <input type="number" name="b" /><br /><br />
   <input type="submit" name="input" />
  </form>
 @{ 
  var answer = (Solve)ViewBag.Message;
  }
<p>
  @answer.Result;
</p>
```

This is my view. Probably the problem is coming from here. Will be really need some help. Thanks

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: if you wanted to get data from model you need to return model in view.

Comment: @Ravikumar I am not getting my result in the view. But how can i return the model to the view

Comment: return View(equation);

Comment: @WillyDavidJr I am having problem bringing my model to the view

Comment: @Ravikumar please I am still getting errors

Comment: It is showing me Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference in the browser

Comment: @Ravikumar I have gotten it fixed up. You are great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return you model like below.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Solve equation)
        {

            equation.Result = equation.a + equation.b;
            return View(equation);
        }
```

Your HTMl will be:

```
@model Test.Models.Solve

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>


<form method="post">
  First Value: <input type="number" name="a"/><br /><br />
  Second Value: <input type="number" name="b" /><br /><br />
   <input type="submit" name="input" />
  </form> 
<p>
  @Model.Result;
</p>
```